# Iteratively fit regression line on subset of pandas DataFrame - vectorized solution?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, linear-regression

I am trying to aggregate pandas DataFrame and create 2 new columns that would be a slope and an intercept from a simple linear regression fit.

The dummy dataset looks like this:

```
CustomerID   Month  Value
a                1     10
a                2     20
a                3     20
b                1     30
b                2     40
c                1     80
c                2     90
```

And I want the output to look like this - which would regress `Value` against `Month` for **each** `CustomerID`:

```
CustomerID    Slope   Intercept
a              0.30          10
b              0.20          30
c              0.12          80
```

I know I could run a loop and then for each `customerID` run the linear regression model, but my dataset is huge and I need a vectorized approach. I tried using `groupby` and `apply` by passing linear regression function but didn't find a solution that would work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I tried using* ... where is your trial? Helpful for modules being used. We need a full code block including `import` lines. *didn't find a solution that would work* ... what were your errors or undesired results?

Answer (score 2):

By using `scpiy` with `groupby` , here I am using for loop rather than apply , since `apply` is slower than for loop

```
from scipy import stats

pd.DataFrame.from_dict({y:stats.linregress(x['Month'],x['Value'])[:2] for y, x in df.groupby('CustomerID')},'index').\
     rename(columns={0:'Slope',1:'Intercept'})
Out[798]: 
   Slope  Intercept
a    5.0   6.666667
b   10.0  20.000000
c   10.0  70.000000
```